# Vue3 dynamic import from js

Tags: vuejs3

hello i just joined you,
I want to use `heroicons` dynamically with vue 3 js,
What I want to do is on the `Home` page you see below;  atrribute I want that icon to be called according to the icon name I wrote.

For example in `Home.vue`
There are 2 examples available.
Please I would be happy if you take into account that I am new here and have little experience with vue js while writing an answer. Thank you from now.

This is what I want to do, it doesn't have to be in a .vue template, it can be given as an example as .js.

[heroicons](https://github.com/tailwindlabs/heroicons#vue)

`<my-icon svgIcon="heroicons_outline:menu"></my-icon>`

`<my-icon svgIcon="heroicons_solid:menu"></my-icon>`

```
<template>
  <my-icon svgIcon="heroicons_outline:menu"></my-icon>
  <my-icon svgIcon="heroicons_solid:menu"></my-icon>
</template>
<script>
import MyIcon from "./MyIcon";
export default {
  name: "Home",
  components: {MyIcon},
};
</script>
```

**MyIcon.vue**

```
<template>
  <label class="block font-bold text-md text-gray-700">
    <svgIcon></svgIcon>
  </label>
</template>

<script>
import {svgIcon} from '@heroicons/vue/outline'
import {defineComponent} from 'vue';

export default defineComponent({
  props: ['svgIcon']
})
</script>
```

Comment: I don't think that you should be using `props: ['svgIcon']` in your MyIcon.vue class. You import that svgIcon into the file and then use it.

Comment: You may need to use slots for something like this

Comment: ok how can i do it?